# Count everytime a node it shown in view

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I have a view that show content of a specific content type, based on some exposed filters.

Each node is "owned" by a user, and i want to provide statistics for how many times their node have been shown in a view (not hov many times the node have been viewed fully).

Then i want to provide the owner of the node with statistics like:

Views today, X
Views last 7 days, X.
Views last 30 days, X.

Any smart ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there is a module for that [node view count](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount), from module page:

> Node View Count module allows to count node views. Unlike statistics module, this module records each view of node with user uid and timestamp. So now you can know how many times a user viewed node by day, week, month and etc.

This module is integrated with Views module. You can use it to create different statistics pages, output new not viewed nodes for user and many more.

Comment: That rely on the node being viewed in a full node like domain.com/node/1. What i need is statistics on how many times the node i shown in a view.